# Is mixed effects sensible or even superior to fixed effects when DV is standardized?

Tags: mixed-model

I want to investigate how a certain measure, that is standardized between 0 and 1, differs between subjects and subgroups. I am afraid that a mixed effects model would be not superior to a fixed effects regression, or would it even be flawed/biased due to the normalization? Many thanks for elaborations!

Comment: You need to provide more information. Please explain how the data originate, ad how and why was the DV transformed into [0,1] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixed effects models are used to account for correlations in your outcome variable within some groups or clusters. You haven’t provided sufficient information on how the standardization was done. If it did not affect the correlations, you can still use mixed models.